# Is it possible in Hybris backoffice to have multiples editors for the same qualifier in the same section?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, backoffice

Every time I try to put a different editor for the same qualifier it gets replaced. I tried to use `merge-mode="append"` But it didn't work.
Is it possibile to do what I want?

In my case I am trying to add 2 editors for the qualifier `members` from `B2BUnit`. 
Here is what I have:

```
<context merge-by="type" parent="Company" type="B2BUnit" component="editor-area">
    <editorArea:editorArea xmlns:editorArea="http://www.hybris.com/cockpitng/component/editorArea" >
        <editorArea:tab name="hmc.tab.groups" >
            <editorArea:section name="hmc.section.groups">
                <editorArea:attribute qualifier="groups"/>
                <editorArea:attribute qualifier="members" editor="com.hybris.cockpitng.editor.defaultmultireferenceeditor" />
                <editorArea:attribute
                        editor="de.hybris.platform.platformbackoffice.editors.membersfindereditor.MembersFinderEditor"
                        qualifier="members" label="hmc.text.usergroup.usesearchtogetmembers" merge-mode="append"/>
            </editorArea:section>
        </editorArea:tab>
    </editorArea:editorArea>
</context>
```

Comment: No its not, but you can add additional dynamic field and and do your logic there

Answer (score 0):

I would assign a custom editor with a custom renderer where you put your own logic combining two or more editors.